# $wpdb not working

Tags: database, forms, sql

I am trying to insert some values inside the database from the form but it's not getting inserted.

MY CODE:

```
<form action="" method="post" >
    <label for="fullname">Fullname</label>
    <input type="text" id="fname" name="fname">
    <label for="fbname">Facebook URL </label>
    <input type="text" id="fbname" name="fbname">
    <input type= "submit" value ="Submit" name="submit">
</form>

<?php
        if(isset($_POST['submit'])){

            global $wpdb;

            $name= $_POST['fname'];
            $fb= $_POST['fbname'];
            $table = $wpdb->prefix.'ssuser';
            $vds= array('nami' => $name,'ffbb' => $fb);     
            $sse=$wpdb->insert($table,$vds);

            if($sse){ echo'Data insert successful';}

            else { echo 'Data insert failed ';}
        }
?>
```

my database

[image]

not insert any data?

Comment: What is your table prefix as set in wp-config.php?

Comment: no, i don,t set table prefix in wp-config.php

Comment: $table_prefix  = 'wp_';

Comment: Your code is trying to insert into a table named `wp_ssuser`, but according to your image the table appears to be named just `ssuser`.